# Calculating the intersection of two spaces of polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, polynomials, vector-spaces

This problem is driving me nuts. I feel like there should be an elementary argument, yet I have failed to find one. Consider the vector space $V_n=\mathbb Q[x]/{x^{2n+1}}=\mathbb Q\{1,x,x^2,\ldots, x^{2n}\}$. Define polynomials $p_m=x^m+(-1-x)^m+(-1-x)^{2n-m}$. Consider the subspaces of $V_n$ given by $$I=\mathbb Q\{p_m\,:\, 0\leq m\leq 2n\},$$ $$J=\mathbb Q\{x^{2i}\,:\,0\leq i\leq n\}$$ and $$K=\mathbb Q\{x^{2i}-x^{2n-2i}\,:\,0\leq i\leq n\}.$$ I want to prove that $$I\cap J= K.$$ Inclusion in the reverse direction is clear: $p_m-p_{2n-m}=x^m-x^{2n-m}$. The hard part is showing the inclusion $I\cap J\subset K$.

Computer calculations show this is true for all $n$ I have checked.

**Update:** I have asked this question at [mathoverflow.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/200658/dimensions-of-a-vector-space-akin-to-modular-symbols)

**Update 2:** This question now has an answer at mathoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If the leading term of your polynomial is $Cx^{2n}$ then start by adding $C(x^{2n} - x^{2n-2})$ to your final answer. Then if the next term is $Bx^{2n-2}$, then add $(C+B)(x^{2n-2} - x^{2n-4})$. And so forth, always setting the next leading coefficient to be the right answer based on what you add from your basis.

Comment: I do not see how this proves the claim.

Comment: Where are you using specific properties of the polynomials $p_n$?